# before post update hook in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hook

My question is If there is a hook that we can check that **post_meta** has been changed or not. In simply word I want to check **post_meta** has change or not when I update the post in wordpress. If there is solution, please help me out. Every suggestion will be appreciable for me. Thanks

Comment: How about using the [updated_post_meta](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/16840) hook

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will give you some direction.

[Action hook "post updated"](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/post_updated)

Comment: this is only matched wp_posts but I want to match post_meta